# Call a method of "Activity extended" class from "ListActivity extended"

Tags: java, android, android-activity, abstract-class, listactivity

Here is the snippet of "MyBaseActivity" Class.

```
public class MyBaseActivity extends Activity {
      public void resetDisconnectTimer()
       {
         disconnectHandler.removeCallbacks(disconnectCallback);
         disconnectHandler.postDelayed(disconnectCallback, DISCONNECT_TIMEOUT);
       }

       @Override
        public void onUserInteraction()
       {
           resetDisconnectTimer();
        }
 }
```

My App contains many classes that extend "Activity" and couple of others extend listActivity. For the classes, extending Activity, I can just extend the "MyBaseActivity" and call the method as:

```
     @Override
     public void onUserInteraction() 
    {
        resetDisconnectTimer();
    }
```

But what about for the classes that extending listactivity ? Any ideas how we can solve it ??

Comment: Use Interface if Possible

Comment: @koutuk, not practical. I have to define the methods in main class, so I could just call it from other classes.

Answer (score 0):

You can switch to fragments so:

```
class MyActivity extends MyBaseActivity { 
@Override protected void onUserInteraction() {..}
}

class MyBaseActivity extends FragmentActivity {
protected void onUserInteraction() {...}
}
```

Then you some of your subclasses of `BaseActivity` have a `ListFragment` in them. To make the porting easier assign `id` of `@android:id/list` to that `ListFragment`.